# OpenACC: memory management

Tags: cuda, openacc

I'm using the CAPS [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC) compiler. Can I manage memory myself?

For example, regular OpenACC code with [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) is :

```
#pragma acc kernels copyin(a,b) copy(c)
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
  for (j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
    for (k = 0; k < SIZE; ++k)
      c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
```

I want change in this way:

```
// Allocation
cudaMalloc((void**)&a, num_bytes);
cudaMalloc((void**)&b, num_bytes);
cudaMalloc((void**)&c, num_bytes);

// Transfer-in
cudaMemcpy(hostA, a, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(hostB, b, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// Computation
// I think it will be generated as a codelet by the CAPS OpenACC compiler.
#pragma acc kernels
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
  for (j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
    for (k = 0; k < SIZE; ++k)
      c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];

cudaMemcpy(c, hostC, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaFree(&a);cudaFree(&b);cudaFree(&c);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can allocate the memory yourself. In your example, it should be possible to achieve this using the  `device_ptr` pragma, so something like:

```
cudaMalloc((void**)&a, num_bytes);
cudaMalloc((void**)&b, num_bytes);
cudaMalloc((void**)&c, num_bytes);

cudaMemcpy(hostA, a, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(hostB, b, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

#pragma acc data deviceptr(a, b, c)
#pragma acc kernels
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
      for (k = 0; k < SIZE; ++k)
        c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];

cudaMemcpy(c, hostC, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaFree(a);cudaFree(b);cudaFree(c);
```

<sub>(Disclaimer: It was written in the browser, never compiled or tested. Use it at your own risk.)</sub>

This should declare that `a`, `b` and `c` are pre-existing allocations to the compiler. You should also be able to use the OpenACC `acc_malloc` routine to allocate memory in place of `cudaMalloc`, if you so wish.

<sub>Thanks to [user2054656 for pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349400/openacc-memory-management/16355136#16355136) my incorrect use of `device_resident` in the first version of this answer.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the [talonmies' post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349400/openacc-memory-management/16354190#16354190), except that you should use the `deviceptr` clause of the `data` pragma. I say this because `device_resident` does request the OpenACC implementation to allocate memory, while *device_ptr* does not.

You don't need to allocate memory, because it's already allocated by the user with `cudaMalloc()`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I was posting from memory on a train when I wrote my answer and got the intent of `device_resident` wrong...